# My Navigation bar is not switching between fragments in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, navigationview

1. activity

```
class ChangeInfoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_info)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConf = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(

            R.id.navigation_person, R.id.navigation_chat

        ))

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConf)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }

}
```

2. layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundsecond"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChangeInfoActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_shape"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/red"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_review" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

3. nav_graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/personFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/personFragment"
        android:name="com.example.autentification.fragments.PersonFragment"
        android:label="fragment_person"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_person" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_personFragment_to_chatFragment"
            app:destination="@id/chatFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chatFragment"
        android:name="com.example.autentification.fragments.ChatFragment"
        android:label="fragment_chat"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chat" >
        <argument
            android:name="nameofuser"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="unnamed warrior" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

4. menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_person"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        android:title="Person" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_chat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_message_24"
        android:title="Chat"/>

</menu>
```

It seems that I have everything done well however I still can't switch between 2 fragments.
(P.S First time asking on this platform sorry for this mess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the fragments IDs in the `navGraph` to be the same as the IDs of the menu

Applying that to the `navGraph`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_person">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_person"
        android:name="com.example.autentification.fragments.PersonFragment"
        android:label="fragment_person"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_person" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_personFragment_to_chatFragment"
            app:destination="@id/chatFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_chat"
        android:name="com.example.autentification.fragments.ChatFragment"
        android:label="fragment_chat"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chat" >
        <argument
            android:name="nameofuser"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="unnamed warrior" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: you are my saver <3

Comment: @GiorgiNinidze So glad to hear that .. please consider to accept the answer by ticking on the left tick mark .. so that it might help someone in the future ,, thank you